# Populate TextBoxes from a List

Tags: c#

I am trying to populate TextBoxes from a list.  I have been able to populate ComboBoxes with comboList:

```
var comboList = new System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox[4];

comboList[0] = cmbSite1Asset;
comboList[1] = cmbSite2Asset;
comboList[2] = cmbSite3Asset;
comboList[3] = cmbSite4Asset;

List<CRCS.CAsset> assets = _rcs.Assets;
foreach (CRCS.CAsset asset in assets)
{
    string id = asset.ID;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        comboList[i].Items.Add(id);
    }
}
```

But when I try and apply the same principle to TextBoxes

```
var aosList = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox[8];

aosList[0] = txtAsset1;
aosList[1] = txtAsset2;
aosList[2] = txtAsset3;
aosList[3] = txtAsset4;
aosList[4] = txtAsset5;
aosList[5] = txtAsset6;
aosList[6] = txtAsset7;
aosList[7] = txtAsset8;

foreach (CRCS.CAsset asset in assets)
{
    string id = asset.ID;

    for (int n = 0; n < 8; ++n)
    {
        aosList[n].Items.Add(id);
    }
}
```

TextBox does not like Items.Add ( aosList[n]Items.Add(id);  )
I am looking fore a reference or guidance resolving this issue.  Thanks!

Comment: Textboxes are not combo boxes, and even if they were, you forgot a period.

Comment: So what is `Items` for a text box?

Comment: You need a `.` between `aoList[n]` and `Items` for the language to kind of make sense. But as sstan said - `TextBox` does not have an `Add` method. What would you expect the `Add` method to do to a `TextBox`?

Comment: I understand they are not.  Period corrected.

Comment: The `TextBox` class does not have an `Items` property: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox

Comment: @João  The list is created by reading an XML file.  I am trying to populate texboxes with the <asset>

Comment: Thanks for the help all.  I'll check the reference provided.

Comment: Then set the `Text` of the `TextBox` to that value :)

Comment: @João - .Text  now I'm getting somewhere - thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [Combobox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) is a collection of items, and so has an `Items` property from which you can add/remove to change it's contents. A [Textbox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox(v=vs.110).aspx) is just a control that displays some text value, so it has a `Text` property which you can set/get, and which denotes the string that is displayed.

```
System.Windows.Forms.TextBox[] aosList = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox[8];

aosList[0] = txtAsset1;
aosList[1] = txtAsset2;
aosList[2] = txtAsset3;
aosList[3] = txtAsset4;
aosList[4] = txtAsset5;
aosList[5] = txtAsset6;
aosList[6] = txtAsset7;
aosList[7] = txtAsset8;

for (int n = 0; n < 8; ++n)
{
    aosList[n].Text = assets[n].ID; // make sure you have 8 assets also!
}
```

Comment: aosList[n].Text = id; returns the last <asset> XML value into all text boxes.  It is close.  Thank you.

Comment: When I put a breakpoint in and debug I can see id cycle through all the <asset> values

Comment: @Sully Yes that's because you have an inner `for` inside a `foreach` loop .Please check edited answer.

Answer (score 2):

You should use ComboBox for your problem,instead of iterating on each element,You simply use below lines to populate combobox.

```
comboList.DataSource=assets;
comboList.DisplayMember="ID";
comboList.ValueMember="ID";
```

However,if you want your values in `TextBox`,you can use `TextBox.AppendText` Method, but it will not work like `ComboBox` as it will contain texts+texts+texts, will not have indexes like `ComboBox.`

```
private void AppendTextBoxLine(string myStr)
{
    if (textBox1.Text.Length > 0)
    {
        textBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
    }
    textBox1.AppendText(myStr);
}

private void TestMethod()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        AppendTextBoxLine("Some text");
    }
}
```

Comment: I can set the DataSource, DisplayMamber and ValueMember but no data displayed in the ComboBox.  I changed the DropDownStyle to Simple and this look will work for the status panel I am designing.  There are 40 TextBoxes.  I will continue to work on the DataSource issue.

Comment: I did, I was not able to get a DataSource.  Your suggestion did open up a new way of working with the ComboBox - I was unaware of that capability.  I appreciate that - thanks!

Comment: @Sully Enjoy Coding

Answer (score 0):

```
int i = 1;
foreach (var asset in assets)
{
    this.Controls["txtAsset" + i].Text = asset.ID;
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Controls returns this error:  Error 1 Non-invocable member 'System.Windows.Forms.Control.Controls' cannot be used like a method.

Comment: @Sully ops .. has to be square brackets in C#